# Redux converting functions to objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I was trying to import and use a function which returns a json object. This function uses some redux state variables in it.
But when I call this to return the json, it returns me something else instead of the said json.

My function is something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const GenerateYaml = (props) => {
    let json = {};
    json = props.selected;
    return json;
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        selected: state.stepBuilder.selected,

    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(GenerateYaml);
```

When I tried to log what was returned, I got to know that it was an object of the connect function. I cant paste is here since its too big. 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: pass the redux `props` to `GenerateYaml ` function where you are calling it

Comment: @SohanPatil `mapStateToProps` will pass them.

Comment: @rajesh im saying that instade of using `mapStateToProps ` in current component it should be used in the component where the function call is there

Comment: Thanks @Sohan that might actually be a good work around.
But is it posible to use redux directly? I know that redux can be used with plain javascript too but can we do it in a react app is a question to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A jsfiddle/codesandbox would be very helpful here,
What I do in such cases is read the expected value in every line of the code, eg use a debugger!

Also `GenerateYml` should return a React component (html) not json.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const GenerateYaml = (props) => {
    const json = { ...props.selected }
    console.log(json);
    return (
      <div>{JSON.stringify(json)}</div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        selected: state.stepBuilder.selected,
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(GenerateYaml);
```

Comment: I want to use this object for further calculations not just display it. Can't I use it to return a object like a simple javascript function?

Comment: "The connect() function connects a React component to a Redux store." so the answer is no. If you want your calculations to be applied in the store do it inside the reducer of the stepBuilder, if you want to use it in multiple components but not keep the affect the store use [redux selectors instead](https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data), If you want to calculate this for just one component do it inside the component you want.

Comment: No problem @Saransh